# Remove leading and trailing whitespaces in JSON keys

Tags: mysql, sql, json, mariadb

I am trying to get a JSON value from my MariaDB server using JSON_EXTRACT. However, there are some JSON keys having lot of white spaces like end of line, space, tabs etc. The data is already there. Hence I am not able to give the correct key name because the key contains white spaces. Please note that the white spaces are there in JSON values also, but we can use TRIM() function to remove the white spaces from values. But what can we do to trim the key names?

For example:

```
CREATE TABLE test.product_json_table (
   id INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
   product VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
   description LONGTEXT ASCII,
  PRIMARY KEY (id),
    CHECK (JSON_VALID(description))
) ENGINE = InnoDB ROW_FORMAT = DEFAULT;



INSERT INTO test.product_json_table(product, description) 
VALUES( 'truck_space', '{"     \r\nwheels  ": 4, "seats": 3, "  fuel   ": "diesel", "  \r\n mileage     ": 8}');
```

The below query does not work:

```
SELECT id, product, description 
FROM test.product_json_table
WHERE JSON_EXTRACT(description, '$.wheels') > 2;
```

The query does not work because there are white spaces be the JSON key "wheels". Same is the case with the key "mileage".

How do we solve this issue? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I would solve the issue by trimming whitespace in your input before you insert it to the database. But you may also be able to extract a quoted key: `JSON_EXTRACT(description, '$." \r\nwheels  "')`. I am not near a MySQL 5.7 instance right now, so I can't test that.

Comment: Also this has nothing to do with your question, but I would recommend using the [JSON data type](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json.html) instead of LONGTEXT.

Comment: All I can say is GIGO.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. The problem I forgot to mention is that I do not have write access to the database. It's being populated by another application. So let me try Bill's suggestion. Oh, I am using MariaDB 10.2.3 and hence there's no JSON data type, they recommend using LONGTEXT. Will update after I try. Thank you all!

Comment: Rick, you're right. It's a typical GIGO issue. But the garbage is dumped into the database by another application where we don't have much control.

Comment: Hi Bill, what Nick suggested below only works..Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In addition to @BillKarwin's suggestion to trim whitespace before you enter it into the database, you can also update all the values in the database to remove the spurious whitespace:

```
UPDATE product_json_table
SET description = REGEXP_REPLACE(description, '\\s|\\r|\\n','');
```

Then your original query will work:

```
SELECT id, product, description 
FROM product_json_table
WHERE JSON_EXTRACT(description, '$.wheels') > 2;
```

Output:

```
id  product         description
1   truck_space     {"wheels":4,"seats":3,"fuel":"diesel","mileage":8}
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=2b21bd90bd96da272d9f6420f8aecd75)

**Update**

You can also perform the whitespace replacement on the fly although this will be much less efficient than permanently removing it with the `UPDATE` query above:

```
SELECT id, product, REGEXP_REPLACE(description, '\\s|\\r|\\n','') AS description 
FROM product_json_table
WHERE JSON_EXTRACT(REGEXP_REPLACE(description, '\\s|\\r|\\n',''), '$.wheels') > 2
```

Output:

```
id  product         description
1   truck_space     {"wheels":4,"seats":3,"fuel":"diesel","mileage":8}
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=0363c655f5898f1251d3439387800525)

Comment: Seems like this only will work. Without update, this is not working. Trying to get write access to the database, not sure if we ever can..

Comment: Wow! Thanks Nick. You saved my day! Marking as answered.

Answer (score 1):

you can use

```
REGEXP_REPLACE(query, '\\s|\\r|\\n','')
```

see

> ```
> CREATE TABLE product_json_table (
>    id INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
>    product VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
>    description LONGTEXT ASCII,
>   PRIMARY KEY (id),
>     CHECK (JSON_VALID(description))
> )
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO product_json_table(product, description) 
> VALUES( 'truck_space', REGEXP_REPLACE('{"     \r\nwheels  ": 4, "seats": 3, "  fuel   ": "diesel", "  \r\n mileage     ": 8}', '\\s|\\r|\\n',''));
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> select * from product_json_table
> ```
>
> ```
> id | product     | description                                       
> -: | :---------- | :-------------------------------------------------
>  1 | truck_space | {"wheels":4,"seats":3,"fuel":"diesel","mileage":8}
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=805155be713c1cc243d4c69f6ab68e58)*